# Windows Server 2012 R2 Stuck While Rebooting at Spinning Blue Windows Screen

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I have recently installed Windows Server 2012 R2 and also installed Backup Exec 2016, after complete the installation windows needs to update and then restart.

After restart the problem came, the server hangs at the Windows Logo, then I have tried to force restart but the problem still occurs, it hangs at the Windows Logo.

My server is a HPE ProLiant DL360 Gen9, with 4 disks configured in RAID 1+0

The big issue is this server already installed with VHP Hotel Program and running smooth, we cannot afford VHP software guy to re install in this server if we reformat and re install Windows (cost issue).

The problem came after Windows update and the following restart.

Comment: When having general boot problems like this, you might [try some of these troubleshooting steps](https://superuser.com/a/977835/149378).